# How can i select from table by OID in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there any way to execute query like:

`SELECT * FROM 17187::regclass;`

where `SELECT 17187::regclass;` → `tablename`

It's easy to achieve this within function by `EXECUTE`, but i'm wondering to do it without functions.

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: it would be like `select * chr(102)||rom tablename` - doable with execute, but why?..

Comment: You probably need the `EXECUTE` but you already know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly need execute.  Here's why:

The SQL queries go through a pipeline as they are executed.  This is done roughly as follows:

1. Query is parsed for identifiers vs values
2. If applicable a "portal" is created and value literals filled in from parameters
3. If applicable, the query is planned and optimized
4. The query is executed.

One consequence of this is that you can only parameterise value literals, and can never parameterise identifiers.  Also utility statements are never planned or parameterised (so you cannot parameterise anything in `create user` though that is peripheral to this discussion).

I don't see any reason why such is fundamentally impossible but it is not supported currently by the way PostgreSQL works.